# NoReverseMatch at / | Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django

Reverse for 'customer' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P[^/]+)/$']

**This is the error**,

Request Method:    GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'customer' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['customer/(?P[^/]+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:
['C:\Users\user\Downloads\Git Project\firstwebsite',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 09 Jun 2021 06:20:15 +0000

This is code

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer, name="customer"),
    path('product/', views.product, name="product"),
]
```

this is models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.FloatField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
        ('Outdoor', 'Outdoor')
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):

    #we create a dropbox like this
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Out Of Deliery', 'Out Of Delivery'),
        ('Deliverder', 'Delivered'),
        )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    date_crated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

This is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Customer, Order, Product


# Create your views here.
def dashboard(request):
    customer = Customer.objects.all()
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    total_customer = customer.count()
    total_orders = orders.count()
    delivered = orders.filter(status='delivered').count()
    pending = orders.filter(status='pending').count()
    

    context = {'orders':orders, 'total_orders':total_orders, 'total_customer':total_customer, 'pending':pending,'delivered':delivered, 'customer':customer}
    return render(request, "accounts/dashboard.html", context)

def product(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request,'accounts/products.html' ,{'products':products})

def customer(request, pk):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders = customer.order_set.all()
    order_count = orders.count()
    context = {'customer':customer, 'orders':orders, 'order_count':order_count}
    return render(request, 'accounte/contact.html', context)
```

Templates Dashboard.html (html file)

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load static %}


    <div class="center" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%; ">
        <img src="{% static 'images/welcome.png' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <br>  
    <div class=" justify-content-center" style="padding: 20; width: 60%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
        <h1 class="display-1 " style="text-align: center; font-style: italic;">This is my first website</h1>
        <div style="padding-top: 50;">
            <img src="{% static 'images/186.png' %}" alt="" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%; ">
        </div>
    </div> 
    
    <br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h5>Customers</h5>

        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm-btn-block" href="">Create Customers</a>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Customers: </th>
                    <th>Phone no: </th>
                    
                </tr>
                {% for customers in customer %}
                    <tr>
                        <th><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'customer' customer.id %}">view</a></th>
                        <td>{{customers.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{customers.phone}} </td>
                    
                    </tr>

                {% endfor %}
                
                
            
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h5>Last 5 orders</h5>
        <hr>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" href="">Create Orders</a>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>category</th>
                    <th>Date Ordered</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>

                {% for i in orders %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{i.product}} </td>
                        <td>{{i.product.category}} </td>
                        <td>{{i.date_crated}} </td>
                        <td>{{ i.status }} </td>
                        
                        <td><a href="#">Update</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
                      
                    </tr>
                    
                {% endfor %}
            
              
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% include 'accounts/status.html' %}
    


</div>


{% endblock %}**
```

idk why I am getting error. Help me out!

Comment: You write `{% for customers in customer %}` and then `{% url 'customer' customer.id %}`. `customer` here is the _QuerySet_ and hence there is no `customer.id` you might have meant to write `customers.id` (Notice the `s`, although I would say this is incorrect naming, since what is actually plural is named singular and what is singular is named plural...)

Comment: yeah Thank You , I forgot that..